# how to get the specific key data from multidimensional array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am working with an API where I got data in this format:-

```
[
  0:{
    id: "1"
    name: "ttp"
    platforms:{
       one: "false",
    }
  },

 1:{
    id: "2"
    name: "spt"
    platforms:{
       one: "true",
       two: "true",
    }
  },
},
]
```

The data is very large it has more than 100 indexes. I want to check if platforms are present in the index. Suppose if any index contains platform `one` I want to show its id and don't want to show that index that doesn't have platform `one`, but I am confused how to do this in React.

Here the code I want to change; don't want to use the index `[0]`

```
if (response.status === 200) {
    console.log(response.data)
    list = response.data[0].platforms;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to filter your array and get just the elements you need based on a condition.

In your case :

```
if (response.status === 200) {
    console.log(response.data)
    list = response.data;
    const filteredList = list.filter( (e: any) => (e.platforms.one));
    // filteredList contains just the objects that contains the value one
}
```

Comment: I am using typescript (not expert in this) and getting this error `Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Comment: @MohitChandel I editetd my answer, check it now

Comment: It is returning an empty array and I just want to confirm that either platform one is present in the platforms don't want its value to be true, please look at your code once again, thanku

Comment: Is that value `"true"` and `"false"` are coming from the back end as `boolean` or `string` ?

Comment: as a string but can we condition like `one` is present or not?

Comment: I updated my answer, If the values received are strings then use the commented line and remove the other one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238549/discussion-between-mohit-chandel-and-haroun-darjaj).

Comment: The answer is updated, now it returns just the objects that contains the value of `one`